# Como hacer para que se cierre la sesion de usuario cuando se cierre el navegador o unos minutos en laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Estoy intentando que mi sesion de usuario dure hasta que el usuario cierre el navigador o que solo dure una hora, pero no se si lo estoy haciendo bien, estoy usando laravel 5.7.

Segun tengo entendido en config, en el archivo `session.php`, aqui esta tiene lo siguiente:

```
return [
    ...
    'lifetime' => env('SESSION_LIFETIME', 5),
    'expire_on_close' => false,
    ...
];
```

En donde estoy usando 5 minutos, para probar y en mi archivo .env

```
SESSION_LIFETIME=5
```

Esto para hacer mis pruebas, pero cuando pasa el tiempo la sesion no es borrada se mantiene, pero no se si es aqui donde se usa o tengo que modificar en otro archivo

Comment: Para revisar cuando cierre el navegador, DEBES usar javascript creo... para detectar el cierre mismo y ejecutar una accion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creo que para que te funcione al cerrar o pasada una hora los parámetros serían.

```
return [
    ...
    'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'cookie'),
    'lifetime' => 60,
    'expire_on_close' => true,
    ...
];
```

Toma en cuenta que el parametro `cookie` es la forma en como se guardará la sesión y hay más formas de hacerlo y explicadas en la [documentación](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/session#configuration) de laravel 5.7.